# Как изменить вариант показа Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

У стандартного `Spinner`, при нажатии на него, вызывается контекстное меню, а как сделать так, чтобы выпадал список? Я где-то это раньше видел, но не знаю как называется такое... выпадание, что ли. Подскажите название такой реализации темы, а еще лучше — как ее установить!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" /> //вот этот атрибут
```

Работать будет только в API 11+ (`Android 3.0`). На версиях ниже будет показываться диалогом, как сейчас у вас.